# Float bottom and up

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make code from further down in the html show above code from above it by using CSS.

Basically my html is like this:

```
<div class="showbelow">
show below
</div>

<div class="showabove">
show above
</div>
```

I am wanting the showabove div to show above the showbelow div despite being below it in the html. Is there a way of doing this **without using negative margins** in the css? eg. giving showabove a negative top margin and show below a positive top margin? Both divs are 100% of the container.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a property [`order`](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-flexbox-1/#order-property) to place items on a specific place using flexbox.

**See the following example:**

```css
.container {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
}
.container div {
  border:1px solid red;
}
.showabove {
  order:1;
}
.showbelow {
  order:2;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="showbelow">show below</div>
  <div class="showabove">show above</div>
</div>
```

> Flex items are, by default, displayed and laid out in the same order as they appear in the source document. The order property can be used to change this ordering.
>   https://drafts.csswg.org/css-flexbox-1/#order-property

**Be careful with using `order:-1`!**

```css
.container {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
}
.container div {
  border:1px solid red;
}
.showabove {
  order:-1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="showbelow">show below</div>
  <div class="showmiddle">show middle</div>
  <div class="showabove">show above</div>
</div>
```

**Explanation:** The `order:-1` set the item on the first position of your container, because all the other items has per default `order:0`. It doesn't move the item before the previous item! In your case this solution is working but if you add more items it can be a problem and you have to set the `order` for each item on the container like the example above.

Comment: Great! Thanks alot - just out of interest do you know what order bots will see the content?

Comment: I think this link can help you: http://sprungmarker.de/wp-content/uploads/css-a11y-group/css-a11y-flexbox.html. For search engines I can't say how it looks like, but I think the search engine gets the stream of the site: `showbelow` before `showabove`.

Answer (score 2):

With `Flexbox` you can change order of elements. So in this case you can use `order: -1` on `.showabove` div.

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.showabove {
  order: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="showbelow">show below</div>
<div class="showabove">show above</div>
```